# How to find out where or if MYSQL5 logs are stored on a machine WHM/Cpanel

Tags: linux, sql-server, mysql, log-files, paths

- I have a WHM/Cpanel re-seller hosting account on a virtual private server (Linux).
- I have root access to the machine via SSH

---

I am trying to locate a file that contains information that will help me to determine which users have accessed what db and from which hosts.

I would imagine this kind of data is stored in a log file somewhere.

The MySQL page  says:

```
The general query log - Established client connections and statements received from clients
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

It also says:

```
By default, all log files are created in the mysqld data directory.
```

So, I am am NOT asking where are the general query log logs stored,  (cos I expect I will get answers saying "it depends")

Please help me work out:

### "How can go about finding out where MySQL general query log logs are stored on a linux machine"

Couple of things i've already tried:

I looked at

```
 /etc/my.cnf
```

it was a tiny file that only contained the following info:

```
[mysqld]
skip-bdb
skip-innodb
set-variable = max_connections=500
safe-show-database
~
~
```

I have looked in:

```
/var/lib/mysql/
```

But I could not see any log-like file names in that directory.

Any clues on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To ask MySQL where it is storing the general logs (and whether they are on or not), you can simply type:

```
 show variables like 'general_log%';
```

Into a MySQL command prompt (or run the query from phpmyadmin).

e.g.

```
mysql> show variables like 'general_log%';
+------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                      |
+------------------+----------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                        |
| general_log_file | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.log |
+------------------+----------------------------+
```

I think that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the general query log specifically at the command line:

```
mysqld ... --log=[filename]
mysqld .. -l [filename]
```

Look at mysqld's command line in the output of `ps ax` to determine if and where your server is logging information.

FWIW, The default location for the general log is the same directory as the data files and it is named `[hostname].log`.

**NB:** if you enable the general query log, the log can get large very quickly.

Comment: thanks. So do you mean i just login via SSH and type [# ps ax] into the SSH command line and it will tell me. I have looked up the man page for "ps" but cannot see how it relates to "ax". Anyway - its a start thanks - i will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian, mysql logs are usually stored under /var/log/mysql/. Derivatives like Ubuntu will also have logs there. If logrotate is installed, it will keep gzipped copies of daily mysql logs for several days (this is configurable).

I assume other Linux distros could have logs in a similar location, e.g. /var/logs/something.

As serverninja points out, general log is disabled by default - so you have to enable it, either from my.cnf or a command line. It will hurt performance badly!

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be within /var/lib/mysql/
ENABLE your general query log